# Automatically progress to next page via clicking? (Automation)

Tags: scripting, automation, web

I have a job that requires a lot of tedious clicking throughout a website as part of the workflow. In one step, I click a link, go to the page, then ALWAYS click a link on that page. I wish I could just go to that link directly, as it would greatly speed things up.

Is there a way to do this? Or to very quickly select the correct link?

In my case I have to click edit on an image, and then the next page is a list of ways to edit the image, and the link I click is always the same because we always use the same way to edit an image.

Comment: If you're using firefox, then [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) could probably help you.  Check out the tutorials and make your own userscript! (Or post another question if the script you make doesn't work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What browser do you use? I have some experience in writing plugins in Google Chrome, but not any other. I don't think the differences are that big really. An example with Chrome:

Create a new folder, and two new files - manifest.json and myscript.js

Code for the manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "My awesome script",
"description": "Some description",
"version": "1.0",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://www.mypage.com/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "myscript.js"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Change the "matches" to the pages you want it to inject with you custom script, and change the js file to whatever file you'd like to run. I often tend to include jquery as well (to do this, simply type

```
        "js": [
            "myscript.js",
            "jquery.js"
        ]
```

A way to do this with JQuery/JS could be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var autoLink = $("#imageID").attr('href');
document.location=autoLink;

});
```

I hope this answered your question.

Edit: To load the script - open the page chrome://extensions/ and select "Load unpacked script" or something like that (I don't have it in english) and select the folder you created. Voila.

Comment: Sort of a silly question I presume, but I assume I'm coding in myscript.js with the jQuery code being in the jquery.js file. However, does it matter that the jquery file is listed second, rather than first?

Comment: No questions are silly! That's right, and I don't think it matters in which order you load the scripts. I use to have JQuery first though (because if it should matter, I want to load the library before I try to code with it). Tell me if you need any help writing the Javascript :)